# Drag and drop for Ionic 2

Tags: drag-and-drop, ionic2, touchscreen

I'm building a tool with Ionic 2, which needs to implement drag and drop functionality. In the beginning I was testing everything in the browser using ionic serve, everything was working, coordinates of dragged images were stored in a SqlStorage (I'm using Ionic2 beta11).

But then I start testing on mobile device, and noticed that dragstart, dragend, dragover events doesn't work on it. I changed these to touchstart, touchmove, touchend, but then I faced problems, because there are limited properties of these events, so I cant access some which I was using when testing in browser.

So my question would be if there is there another events for using drag and drop for mobile devices?

Comment: Please let me know which lib you have used to implement drag n drop (native html api / share github link)

Comment: Hi @Zygi was you able to get drag and drop work in ionic2, also for mobile devices?